Strategy.exit() lacks info about profit or loss made
I'd like to add a comment under every strategy.exit() on my chart, displaying the amount of profit or loss, but I can't find an easy way to do that, other than manually setting up a saparate condition, outside that scope, about price met and the amount of position that's being closed if the take profit is partial.
I really find odd that there's no built-in variable telling you the value of the just-closed trade, given the fact that you will find it anyways in the list of trades.
When I close the position "manually" (inside an if statement), I'm used to use
lastTradeProfit := strategy.openprofit

before closing the position and then add that to the comment. But that works only if you close the entire position and if you do it manually.
If you use strategy.exit() to automatically close the position, maybe partially, that cannot be used.
Any ideas?

It has everything you need. You just need to know how to use them.
Use strategy.closedtrades to see if there is a trade closed partially or fully.
Then loop over those closed trades and use strategy.closedtrades.*() functions to get the information you need.
Below is a small example. It plots information regarding the closed trades whether it is a reversal, partial or full position close.
//@version=5
strategy("My strategy", overlay=true, max_labels_count=500)

sma_fast = ta.sma(close, 15)
sma_slow = ta.sma(close, 80)

plot(sma_fast, "Fast SMA", color.green)
plot(sma_slow, "Slow SMA", color.red)

longCondition = ta.crossover(sma_fast, sma_slow)
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)

shortCondition = ta.crossunder(sma_fast, sma_slow)
if (shortCondition)
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)

is_long = (strategy.position_size > 0)
is_short = (strategy.position_size < 0)

tp1_per = 1 * 0.01
tp2_per = 2 * 0.01

float tp1_price = is_long ? (strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + tp1_per)) : is_short ? (strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - tp1_per)) : na
float tp2_price = is_long ? (strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + tp2_per)) : is_short ? (strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - tp2_per)) : na

plot(tp1_price, "TP1", color.green, 1, plot.style_circles)
plot(tp2_price, "TP2", color.lime, 1, plot.style_circles)

plotchar(bar_index, "bar_index", "", color=color.white)

if (is_long)
    strategy.exit("LE1", "Long", limit=tp1_price, qty_percent=50)
    strategy.exit("LE2", "Long", limit=tp2_price, qty_percent=100)

if (is_short)
    strategy.exit("SE1", "Short", limit=tp1_price, qty_percent=50)
    strategy.exit("SE2", "Short", limit=tp2_price, qty_percent=100)

if (strategy.closedtrades > strategy.closedtrades[1])
    for i=strategy.closedtrades to strategy.closedtrades[1]
        s = "Entry ID: " + strategy.closedtrades.entry_id(i) + "\n"
        s := s + "Entry Idx: " + str.tostring(strategy.closedtrades.entry_bar_index(i)) + "\n"
        s := s + "Entry Price: " + str.tostring(strategy.closedtrades.entry_price(i), format.mintick) + "\n"
        s := s + "Exit ID: " + strategy.closedtrades.exit_id(i) + "\n"
        s := s + "Exit Idx: " + str.tostring(strategy.closedtrades.exit_bar_index(i)) + "\n"
        s := s + "Exit Price: " + str.tostring(strategy.closedtrades.exit_price(i), format.mintick)

        label.new(strategy.closedtrades.exit_bar_index(i), high, s, textcolor=color.white)



I'm not sure this helps in what I wish to achieve. If I wanted to add a label I could easily do it. And strategy.closedtrades.profit() can retrieve the value. The problem is doing it inside the strategy.exit() line, adding the profit (or loss) as a comment.
I can't find a useable "event" to freeze the value, as it always displays the same trade.
e.g.
ltp = strategy.closedtrades.profit(strategy.closedtrades-1)
strategy.exit(blablabla, comment=+str.tostring(ltp))
The comment always displays the last trade profit.

You cannot do that. strategy.exit() places an exit order in the order book at the time you call this function. You cannot add a variable whose value will be known in the future when you place this exit order.
